# Unconstrained lifetime on nightly, design advice needed

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am a bit stuck on some code, http://is.gd/OMvnN7 : a bug fix on nightly makes it invalid (for good reason : https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/24461), but I don't see any alternative to make my code run.

The point is my associated type 'SignedContent' got an associated lifetime most of the time, but I do not want to bind this lifetime to its parent trait (the impact on existing code is likely to be that every traits using this traits (a lot) will need an additional lifetime parameter which does not look too practical).

I may end switching to a 'get_sign_content' returning a `Vec<u8>` directly, but I really prefer to return an encodable struct.

The only thing missing is the expressiveness for saying my associated type lifetime bound is the same as its parent, Something like that (invalid)

```
impl TrustedVal for RSAPeer
{
    type SignedContent = TrustedPeerToSignEnc<'Self::lifetime>;
```

Or

```
impl<'a> TrustedVal for RSAPeer where RSAPeer : 'a
{
    type SignedContent = TrustedPeerToSignEnc<'a>;
```

I also consider (this is valid)

```
impl<'a> TrustedVal for &'a RSAPeer
{
    type SignedContent = TrustedPeerToSignEnc<'a>;
```

but it becomes really awkward with some other code. Any ideas on the right way to design this ?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to implement the original form is with (a limited form of) higher-kinded types, allowing something like `trait TrustedVal { type SignedContent<'a>: Encodable; fn get_sign_content(&'a self) -> Self::SignedContent<'a>; }`, `impl TrustedVal for RSAPeer { type SignedContent<'a> = TrustedPeerToSignEnc<'a>; ...`. Unfortunately, this feature doesn't exist now/yet.

Comment: Indeed that was the original intent.

Answer (score 3):

One way to fix it is to make the lifetime parameter a parameter on the trait. This works well especially when you only have one method in the trait:

```rust
pub trait TrustedVal<'a> {
  type SignedContent : Encodable ;
  fn get_sign_content(&'a self) -> Self::SignedContent;
}

impl<'a> TrustedVal<'a> for RSAPeer
{
  type SignedContent = TrustedPeerToSignEnc<'a>;

  fn get_sign_content(&'a self) -> TrustedPeerToSignEnc<'a> {
    TrustedPeerToSignEnc {
      version : 0,
      name : &self.name,
    }
  }
}
```

to use such a trait as a bound you may have to use this nifty syntax:

```
where T: for<'a> TrustedVal<'a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code is wrong, at least, the compiler mishandles it, and allows memory unsafety to occur. I suspect it is supposed to be illegal: [#24622](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24622).

Comment: That's sad, but I can't point out something that's wrong in the code. It should indicate the correct kind of borrowing relation between self and the return value.

Comment: Thanks, that was my first attempt, but it has to much impact over my other traits (at least without the nifty syntax). For instance for at Key Value storage trait which  uses TrustedVal and with the additional param, I needed to add the lifetime to the store trait (and so on of other traits) :  http://is.gd/EPat2Q . But with the "nifty syntax" I indead could remove the additional parameter in my trait : http://is.gd/jGO9Zy . I wonder if there is some documentation about this syntax or some similar one allowing me to avoid propagating lifetime to trait such as TrustedPeer in http://is.gd/AIoLLW

Comment: @user139873, right, the code in the answer doesn't inherently have memory unsafety, but it is very easy to trigger with any generic code that uses the trait. It's not clear to me that this is a case of "should", since there's no direct connection between the lifetime of the associated type and the lifetime in the trait, and it's not obvious to me if we want to implicitly impose `'a: Self::SignedContent` (i.e. that `SignedContent` is valid for at *most* `'a`).